# system.indexes in mongodb for backup

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I am using mongodump tool for collecting backup,during this I am excluding some of the collection which I dont need using excludeCollection options.

As part of mongodump we have a system collection system.indexes ,is there any impact during restore if I exclude this collection from backup ?

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation.

> *mongodump* only captures the documents in the database in its backup data and does not include index data.

And ...

> *mongorestore* recreates indexes recorded by *mongodump*.

This is a bit contradictory, but what I get from this is that, index data won't be backed up, that's for sure. On the other hand, *mongorestore* will recreate indexes after the data restore, according to what is defined on the database's *system.indexes* collection previously dumped, which keeps the indexes meta-data. So, I think you shouldn't exclude this collection from your backup.

If you do, then you should recreate indexes manually yourself after the restore.